# How to switch two bases at position specified by user

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I am a beginner in PERL working on the question above. so I got this error 
splice () offset past the end of array, after I used use strict;

I spent hours modifying the code but to no avail so could anyone please explain to me why it doesn't work as layman as possible (I am a total newbie)

Thanks!

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#Ask for input from user
#Then switch two bases at positions specified by the user

print "Enter your DNA string:\n";
my @input_seq = split( //, <STDIN> );
chomp @input_seq;
print "First base: ";    #position of first base
my $base_1_pos = <STDIN>;
chomp $base_1_pos;
my $base_1 = "$input_seq[$base_1_pos]";
print "Second base ";    #position of second base
my $base_2_pos = <STDIN>;
chomp $base_2_pos;
my $base_2 = "$input_seq[$base_2_pos]";
@input_seq = splice( @input_seq, "$base_1_pos", 1, "$base_2" );    #splice $base_2 into $base_1
@input_seq = splice( @input_seq, "$base_2_pos", 1, "$base_1" );    #splice $base_1 into $base_2
print "@input_seq\n\n";                                            #print output
```

Best wishes,
Wei

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs that demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is swap two elements in an array, you don't need `splice` at all.  An [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) does the job much more easily and efficiently:

```
@input_seq[$base_1_pos, $base_2_pos] = @input_seq[$base_2_pos, $base_1_pos];
```

or, if you already have the element values saved in scalar variables:

```
@input_seq[$base_1_pos, $base_2_pos] = ($base_2, $base_1);
```

or even simply:

```
$input_seq[$base_1_pos] = $base_2;
$input_seq[$base_2_pos] = $base_1;
```

(The situation where you need `splice` is when you want to replace a sequence of elements in the middle of the array with a sequence *of different length*.  But if you just want to replace some elements without changing the length of the array, a slice assignment will do just fine.)

Answer (score 1):

Just change these two lines:

```
@input_seq= splice (@input_seq, "$base_1_pos", 1, "$base_2");   #splice $base_2 into $base_1
@input_seq= splice (@input_seq, "$base_2_pos", 1, "$base_1");   #splice $base_1 into $base_2
```

to:

```
splice (@input_seq, $base_1_pos, 1, $base_2);   #splice $base_2 into $base_1
splice (@input_seq, $base_2_pos, 1, $base_1);   #splice $base_1 into $base_2
```

As said in the [doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

> splice ARRAY or EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH,LIST
>   Removes the elements designated by OFFSET and LENGTH from an array,
>   and replaces them with the elements of LIST, if any. In list context,
>   returns the elements removed from the array. In scalar context,
>   returns the last element removed, or undef if no elements are removed.